How does this Paypal guest checkout scam work?
Yesterday I noticed that someone used a Paypal "Guest" checkout with my bank details (IBAN) via SEPA to buy goods worth ~60€ and ship them to an old address of mine. The purchase was made at a small online shop.
I received an e-mail from Paypal (the real one) confirming the purchase and the charge shows on my bank account today. I also received an order confirmation of the shop per e-mail. I called Paypal and they confirmed the transaction but couldn't reverse it.
So someone used my, apparently leaked, e-mail, IBAN and address to order something in my name.
Additionally, I received another order confirmation from the same shop. This order was paid in someone elses name and does not show on my bank statement. I did not receive a Paypal e-mail for the second order.
So someone ordered in my name with another persons bank details some additional goods.
In addition to that and at the same time, I received ~ 70 e-mails for newsletter registrations, maybe to mask the purchase e-mails.
I called the shop and they are reversing the first payment. The second payment wasn't made with my bank details so they'll hold on to that money for now in case the victim of that order reverses the charge themselves. Anyhow, I could also have reversed the charge to my bank account via SEPA and I believe the shop is legitimate.
What I don't understand is where this is going. The money actually reached the shop and not someone else. The refund should go through to me - or is there a way that the refund gets lost onto a scammers account? The charge (Paypal guest account) is linked to my e-mail address, which they do not seem to have had access to (yes, I changed the password anyways). It's also my bank account linked to the purchase.
Has anyone seen something similar or any idea what the goal could be?

Update:
The money has been refunded and shows on my bank account, so it's also not a refund scam of some sort. It remains mysterious. The only ones potentially benefiting from this would be the shop if I didn't notice anything. I don't think they are in on it, but will probably never know for sure.

As always: don't let lack of understanding stop you from being suspicious and taking preventive/corrective action.  (It's interesting to speculate — but scams can be complicated, or you might see only a small part, especially if you're not the main victim.  In fact, some scams depend upon giving the mark a false idea about how the scam works.)

How can anyone use your IBAN to buy anything without you? I don't get it. The IBAN is to send money to, not to just take money from an IBAN number.

@VladimirFГероямслава You can use your IBAN to pay in shops offering "Direct debit" payment. You basically allow the company to withdraw money from your bank account. Usually the authentication for that is a signature, but that doesn't work on the internet. That makes it prone to misuse, which is why the number of shops that offer this seems to be declining. You can have your bank reverse fraudulent direct debit charges.

@towe I am pretty sure one normaly must approve direct debits from my (EU but not eurozone) account in the internet or mobile banking. We use it sometimes for bills like insurance but they cannot continue taking anything when I cancel the approval in the banking app even when I did approve it previously.

@VladimirFГероямслава Right, once you ban the vendor in your bank account they can't deduct any money, but at least in Germany there is no active approval for new direct debit "contracts"; contrary to e.g. payments with my VISA debit and credit cards.

@towe Not, once you ban. I wrote about prior approvel, not a ban post factum. There should be a Unique Mandate Reference for the approved mandate before any direct debit can start.

@VladimirFГероямслава prior approval is not necessary. But reversing the payment is also possible up to 8 weeks after the charge.

@VladimirFГероямслава There is no "prior approval" in Germany, and the mandate reference is generated automatically as far as I know.

@VladimirFГероямслава that is heavily country dependant. Italy has whitelist by default (which is what you're describing), Germany has blacklist by default (aka anyone can unless forbidden)

@VladimirFГероямслава yes that mandate reference exists. It's just that about anyone can generate it since in legitimate shops it's just you clicking on a  "yes they can do that"  checkbox on the checkout page.

It sounds like the shop (either the owners, or someone working there) is misusing stored account details in order to bulk up their sales before Christmas. This could be a seller who's on commission or just someone who plans to mislabel the goods and send them to a different address.

Purely as a guess: testing that your credentials work, and testing whether you are paying attention. If they know they can get away with this, they can set up a repeated slow drain on your account and you might never notice it.

I don't see any way they are getting feedback about what I do or don't or whether the payment went through - the order confirmation email address and PayPal email address are mine and I don't think they had access to it. And the shop seems legit, too.

This seems like a way to use your identity to do stuff, the first orders are just testing your reaction to it and the next ones could be used to order something to a different adresses from different account details. Or stuff online that could be picked up on the site itself. In the end they might use your details for shady stuff like conning/scamming other people using your identity.

@DonQuiKong Most shops display an order number on the post-checkout page. With that number you can track the delivery status

@DonQuiKong Did you confirm that your email credentials weren't also compromised? The shop may seem legit but what if the scammers have a backdoor to their order database? Also, they can camp at the delivery address and check if the order arrived. The possibilities are immense.

Just an idea. When they get the email + IBAN info, they don't know yet if Paypal is allowed to emit IBAN transfer on your account.
Typically, in France, a company can not emit a transfer without prior explicit consent (which is a minimum security, better than nothing).
They don't care about the money and the good they have ordered.
They needed to know if Paypal is allowed to drain your account or not.
How do they know if it worked
They have created an order on a shop that either:

Allow "anonymous" customer, that is, with only an order number, you can check the order status and delivery. In that case, they only need to connect later on to check if the order was canceled.
Allow to create an account with some email and a payment form with another email. In that case, you can ask the shop for the customer informations they have for that order, you'll likely get their email account (but this is likely of low value, temporary email).

How can they gain money
They won't gain money from you. Because you've reverted the transaction, it means that they'll see the order was cancelled. They don't care if it was cancelled because the IBAN account is wrong or because you're monitoring it, this simply mean they can move on to the next user in their list.
If you hadn't reverted the transaction (because you haven't see it), they would have seen the order delivered (and returned or not). This means you are negligent and they can then process further with level 2 scam (see below).
Level 2 scam
Once they know you're negligent, they only need to set up a (dumb) company using Paypal for checkout and selling services. They'll then set up some transactions for this company on your account. Since it goes through Paypal, and not through their company, your bank will accept the SEPA's transfer. They'll simply collect the money directly then.
Please notice that if they directly tried this with their stolen user list, many transfer will be reverted, leading to being banned by Paypal for fraudulent behavior. Doing the first step filtering with a legitimate company moves the "bad" behavior ranking onto it, not their.
What to do now?
Ideally, ask the bank to change your bank account (or open another bank account). If you can't do that, blacklist paypal from your allowed SEPA company, so they won't be able to use Paypal for their actions anymore. If you have other payment processing company allowed on your account, you should blacklist them all (like Stripe, ...). SEPA is made for direct transfer, it's not a tool that can be used by payment processing platform, since you can't identify the source anymore once it's on your account.

The shop does allow anonymously checking the order status via a link I got per e-mail. Maybe the link is also available at checkout. This theory is plausible.

I’m not aware of anything actually preventing transfers without consent in France, unless the bank account owner has set up a generic block on unapproved SEPA transfers (which is the common suggestion following IBAN leaks). By default, transfers are allowed, and banks only check things if customers complain. Companies are supposed to obtain consent, but AFAIK that’s a contractual (and presumably legal) requirement, not a technical one.

@StephenKitt Interesting. I was sure that without presenting a valid mandat de prélèvement, the SEPA transfer would fail. If it doesn't, it's a huge security hole, since with only a non secret information (the IBAN), you can actually empty (or fill) any account.

@xryl669 as I understand it, you need a « mandat de prélèvement », but there are no explicit checks that it’s valid beyond checking the internal IBAN CRC and in some cases matching the account holder name. The security angle has been sacrificed on the altar of convenience; that’s why banks are forced to refund any lost money and incurred fees within one working day of a contested SEPA withdrawal, no questions asked. (They can of course investigate and push back, but the refund comes first.)

By “(dumb) company” do you mean a dummy company, an unwitting scapegoat, or something else?

This may be some new and obscure variant of the brushing scam: fake orders for goods that someone uses to enhance the online reputation of the vendor. This was more common around 2020. The idea being that the fake order enables the scammer to write a fake review of the vendor on the online platform and it passes muster as a "verified purchaser". After building up enough of a reputation they have a better chance of pulling off a variety of other scams. The fact that they had sufficient banking information to actually submit a transaction on your account is concerning. I see you've already changed you email password. If it were me I'd close out my bank account too, and set up 2FA for everything.

It's an inherent feature / flaw of how SEPA direct debit works in Europe. There is no authentication or 2FA, it's just "This is my IBAN, I allow you, the vendor, to collect the payment from there". The vendor is who initiates the transfer, and the bank is supposed to allow that unless you tell your bank otherwise.

@towe Italy has SEPA direct debit on a whitelist model by default and you too can ask your bank to do that and just block any and all SEPA direct debit calls unless whitelisted. @ OP: I would absolutely recommend you to do this!

@Hobbamok That sounds very reasonable. I've looked it up for my bank and they don't seem to offer that, so apparently there's differences within Europe too. Germany seems to be a purely "blacklist" based.

@towe maybe call them or visit a Filiale, even if it's not a regular offering, since you were already victim of a scam they may be able to switch you with some admin access.

This doesn’t make sense. The vendor is described as a “small shop” - they could no doubt create their own fake “verified” reviews without getting involved in exceedingly risky bank fraud. Brushing is for sellers that use third-party marketplaces they don’t control (e.g. Amazon).

Brushing also usually isn't combined with using somebody else's payment credentials in an unauthorized/fraudulent way, I'd assume: Presumably it's quite easy for platforms to delete all reviews for transactions that end up getting disputed, so there would be no point.

@Hobbamok I did call them and they told me they can only reverse the payment, not block it preemptively.

xryl669 answer about testing if the bank details are correct (they have probably bought many records, but as noted, it's old information), by validating if the sale goes through via a link provided by the shop seems spot on. However, I'm not convinced that the final goal would be to create a shop selling services through PayPal.
They could be trying to redirect the shipping to another place, as it's sometimes done in scams, but they don't have access to the email, and it seems odd that the shop would provide the required tracking code on the initial step. It might be in the order status page, though.
I first thought it was an error, but now I suspect there is something going on with the second order.
The first order uses your e-mail, IBAN and physical address. So far, it is consistent. However, the second order uses your email (or perhaps an account created with your email) but a different Name and IBAN. It may have used your address or not.
If the buyer changed the victim being impersonated, it shouldn't have used your email address. This looks like trying to trick someone by making an order with what looks like a previous successful customer. The obvious target would be the shop (if the goods are expensive enough), but it might be some other entity.
‎
Note you should file a police report, even though you didn't lose money this time. The fraudulent use of your data (and likely of many other victims as well) is illegal by itself, and there may be more attempts to either deduct money from your account or even link you to some other fraudulent operation. The report should help you there.
Of course, I would also review the bank account transactions of the past months, to see if there were any other entries you don't recognize, and watch for future attempts. I would also recommend requesting that the bank provides you a new IBAN (the police report may help in that).
